# searching for the source for Kulo Tov?

Tags: commentaries, parashat-bereishit, ramchal, tov-goodness

What is the original source for HaShem being called 'Kulo Tov', 'Completely Good'?
It seems to be the source for the idea that HaShem created the creation to bestow His goodness.

Could anyone explain me if everything is made for human, so human could receive His goodness, and why it is that it isn't handout for free, but human seems to have to work for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the original source, but one example is the Ramchal's "Daas Tvunos" (דעת תבונות) (section 18) who writes that "what him, blessed be his name, wanted, is to create Nivraim in order to bestow good upon them" ("מה שרצה הוא יתברך שמו - לברוא נבראים כדי שיוכל להטיב להם").

I have heard some explain your question by the understanding that if someone receives a rightfully earned  reward it greatly surpasses the goodness that he will feel if he were to be handed the reward for free.

Another understanding is that Evil is only true from a subjective point of view, eventually the outcome will prove that the any Evil served a higher good...

Comment: The Ohaiv Yisrael (Re’ei) based on Tanchuma Re’ei #3, Devarim Rabbah 4:3, Lamentations 3:38: “It is not from the mouth of the Most High that evil and good emanate.” Only good emanates from God. God is “Kulo Tov” – completely and perfectly good. God desires to send only blessing.