# Hatov V'hameitiv origin

Tags: history, blessing, talmud-gemara, commentaries, talmud-bavli

In relation to the following question:[Kulo Tov](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/searching-for-the-source-for-kulo-tov), I wondered who wrote the 
**hatov v'hameitiv** and what its origin is.

(Looking for sources that state that HaShem is [all/completely] good)

Comment: What is "the **hatov v'hameitiv**"? Please [edit] to clarify. A blessing containg those words shows up in a number of places in Halacha.

Answer (score 2):

This is in a Mishna in [Berachos 9:2](http://www.emishnah.com/PDFs/Berakhot09.pdf). The meaning (as stated by Rabbi Ovadia Bartenura there) is that He does good to me and good to others.